# How to add methods or data on current Vue instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to **Vue.js** and I'm messing around with it. Is there a way to create reusable methods and data?

Here's the very simple code I want to achieve:

**page1.html**

```
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" v-on="click: foo()">Foo</button> 
  <button type="button" v-on="click: bar()">Bar</button>
</div>

<script src="reusable.js"></script> 
<script src="page1.js"></script>  <-- Custom script -->
```

**page2.html**

```
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" v-on="click: foo()">Foo</button> 
  <button type="button" v-on="click: baz()">Baz</button>
</div>

<script src="reusable.js"></script> 
<script src="page2.js"></script>  <-- Custom script -->
```

**reusable.js**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'John'
  },
  methods: {
    foo: function(){
      console.log('foo');
    }
  }
});
```

Now I'd like to access the data or add methods on my *reusable.js*'s VM, so I can access it on my *page1.js* or *page2.js*. I have no idea how to do it, but I want to achieve something like this:

**page1.js**

```
// adds a new method on my reusable.js's vm
vm.extend({
  methods: {
    bar: function(){
      // triggers when I click the bar button
      console.log('bar'); 
      console.log(this.name); // John
    }
  }
});
```

**page2.js**

```
// adds a new method on my reusable.js's vm
vm.extend({
  methods: {
    baz: function(){
      // triggers when I click the baz button
      console.log('baz');
      console.log(this.name); // John
    }
  }
});
```

I'm aware that `vm.extend` is wrong (I just give you guys an idea of what I'm trying to achieve).

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I have a solution for what you want by using jQuery combined with Vue. Do you use jQuery in your project?

Comment: @Buzinas - yes. can you give me an example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps you can use mixins? Pretty much like this:

```
var mix = {
    methods : {
        bar : function() {
            console.log('bar')
        }
    }
};

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    mixins : [mix],
    methods : {
        foo: function() {
            console.log('foo')
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dewey92/yMv7y/965/

Source: http://vuejs.org/guide/extending.html

So in your case:

Page1.html:

```
<div id="app">
    <button type="button" v-on="click: foo()">Foo</button> 
    <button type="button" v-on="click: bar()">Bar</button>
</div>

<script src="page1.js"></script>  <-- Custom script (or page2.js) -->
<script src="reusable.js"></script>
```

page1.js:

```
var mix = {
    methods : {
        bar : function() {
            console.log('bar')
        }
    }
};
```

page2.js:

```
var mix = {
    methods : {
        baz : function() {
            console.log('baz')
        }
    }
};
```

reusable.js:

```
var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        mixins: [mix],
        data: {
            name: 'John'
        }
        methods: {
            foo: function(){
                console.log('foo');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a way to extend base Vue variable in child Js without adding a mixin to parent js